# PowerShell: What's wrong with "... ${_.Name} ..."?

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation

Why am i not able to use $_ inside of text as one can use other variables?

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -filter *.mp3 | foreach { 
        $count++;
        write-host "File${count}=${_.Name}"; 
    }
```

I know I can write it this way:

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -filter *.mp3 | foreach { 
        $count++;
        write-host "File${count}=$($_.Name)"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `${_.Name}` you're actually asking for the variable named `_.Name`, not the `Name` property of the `$_` variable.

```
PS > ${_.Name} = "test"
PS > Get-Variable _*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
_.Name                         test
```

The reason `$($_.Name)` works is because `$()` means "process this first", so you can specify whatever you want inside. In this case you just specified a variable name and the property you wanted, but you could also make it more complex like:

```
PS > $a = 1
PS > "A's value is 1(true or false?): $(if($a -eq 1) { "This is TRUE!" } else { "This is FALSE!" })"

A's value is 1(true or false?): This is TRUE!

PS > $a = 2
PS > "A's value is 1(true or false?): $(if($a -eq 1) { "This is TRUE!" } else { "This is FALSE!" })"

A's value is 1(true or false?): This is FALSE!
```